# C++ Structured binding with -Wshadow warnings?

Tags: c++, gcc-warning, stdtuple

update: gcc works, But clang not

---

compile with C++17

GCC/Clang -Wshadow will warn if shadow local variable happens, but with structured bindings, this flag not work. How to expose warning with this situation?

```
std::tuple<int, int> yy = {-1, -2};
int x = 1;
{
  //    int x = 2;   // will warn -Wshadow
  auto [x, y] = yy;  // will not warn even if compile with -weverything 
}
```

Comment: What does your compile string look like? You are using `-std=c++17` (or later)? Since you can use `x` from the structured binding, I would expect a shadowed warning. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fAVHfT) with gcc 9.2 and clang 9.0.0. There my minimal program:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, int> yy = {-1, -2};
void bla(int x)
{
    if (x)
    {
        auto [x, y] = yy;
    }
}
```

Gets a shadow warning in gcc (`-Wall -Wshadow -std=c++17`):

```
<source>: In function 'void bla(int)':

<source>:8:19: warning: declaration of 'auto x' shadows a parameter [-Wshadow]

    8 |         auto [x, y] = yy;

      |                   ^

<source>:4:14: note: shadowed declaration is here

    4 | void bla(int x)

      |          ~~~~^

<source>:8:14: warning: structured binding declaration set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

    8 |         auto [x, y] = yy;

      |              ^~~~~~
```

But not in clang (`-Wall -Wshadow -Wshadow-all -std=c++17`):

```
<source>:8:14: warning: unused variable '[x, y]' [-Wunused-variable]

        auto [x, y] = yy;

             ^

1 warning generated.
```

This is a bug in clang, as reported here: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40858.